# On the density of $A = \{(2^{m}3^{n},5^{m}7^{n}): n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{+}\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A = \{(2^{m}3^{n},5^{m}7^{n}): n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$

-Is $A$ dense in $\mathbb{R}^{+}\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$?

-What is the shape of $D(A)$?(set of accumulation points of A)

I have attempted some things.

First i proved that the projections on the axys are dense (by corollary this means that the projection on any line is dense)

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $b>a$ then we want for some $m,n$ that

$$\log_{2}(b)>m+n\log_{2}(3)>log_{2}(a)$$
if $\log_{2}(a) +1 \leq \log_{2}(b)$ we just choose the $m$ integer in between and $n=0$

Otherwise $m\leq\log_{2}(a)\leq\log_{2}(b)\leq m+1$

But $\{n\log_{2}(3)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ (fractional part) is dense in $[0,1]$.
There exist infinte n-s such that:

$$\log_{2}(a)-m\leq\{n\log_{2}(3)\}\leq\log_{2}(b)-m$$

From which the solution
$$a\leq 3^{n}2^{m}\leq b$$
...follows

I also noticed that it suffices to prove that is is dense in $$(B(0,1+\epsilon)-B(0,1-\epsilon))\cap\mathbb{R}^{+}\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$$
for it to be dense in $\mathbb{R}^{+}\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$

Any insight is appreciated!

**EDIT**: fixed a mistake in the question and added a question mark

**EDIT2**: made the title more descriptive and formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $A \subset \mathbb{R}_+^* \times \mathbb{R}_+^*$ and the map,
$$
\log : \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbb{R}_+^* \times \mathbb{R}_+^* & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\\
(x,y) & \mapsto & (\ln(x),\ln(y)),
\end{array}
\right.
$$
is a homeomorphism. The image by $\log$ of $A$ is $\log(A) = \{(m\ln(2) + n\ln(3),m\ln(5) + n\ln(7))|(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2\} = \mathbb{Z}v \oplus \mathbb{Z}w$ where $v = (\ln(2),\ln(5))$ and $w = (\ln(3),\ln(7))$. As $(v,w)$ is free, $\log(A)$ is a lattice of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. In particular, it is discrete, which means that $\log(A)$ has no accumulating point. We deduce that $A$ has no accumulation point in $\mathbb{R}_+^* \times \mathbb{R}_+^*$. Therefore, $D(A) \subset \{xy = 0\}$. The only accumulation points are on the axis, and in particular, $A$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+$.

Clearly, $(0,0) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} (2^{-n}3^{-n},5^{-n}7^{-n})$ is in $D(A)$. Now, take some $(x,0)$ on the $\{y = 0\}$ axis with $x > 0$. It is in $D(A)$. It is an accumulation point of $A$ if and only if for all $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find sequences $(m_k,n_k)$ of integers such that $2^{m_k}3^{n_k} \rightarrow x$ and $5^{m_k}7^{n_k} \rightarrow 0$.

Using your method, we can find a sequence of integers with $2^{m_k}3^{n_k} \rightarrow x$ and we can choose the $n_k$ positive (thus $n_k \rightarrow +\infty$ and $m_k \rightarrow -\infty$). Then,
$$
5^{m_k}7^{n_k} = (2^{m_k})^{\log_2(5)}7^{n_k} \sim (3^{-n_k})^{\log_2(5)}7^{n_k} = \left(\frac{7}{3^{\log_2(5)}}\right)^{n_k} \rightarrow 0,
$$
because $n_k \rightarrow +\infty$ and $\frac{7}{3^{\log_2(5)}} < 1$. It proves that $D(A)$ contains the half-axis $\{x \geqslant 0, y = 0\}$. We can use the same method (but this time, choose $n_k \rightarrow -\infty$), we can show that it also contains the other axis. Finally,
$$
D(A) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+|xy = 0\},
$$
is the union of the two half axis.

Comment: Nice! In the meanwhile i realized that the $x$ and $y$ axys where in fact part of $D(A)$ and was about to edit. What i didn't see is how it is the entirety of $D(A)$!

Comment: Just to confirm when you say $v$ and $w$ are free you mean linearly independent?

Comment: Yes, it is what I mean